Using Subdivisions and Sculpting Together
I watched a video (had to slow it down) and really liked how by doing some box modeling and then using subdivisions you can still have the good topology underneath.  The thing is, it looks like in the video he can sculpt just using subdivision but for me it doesn’t work well.  He goes back and forth between the lower poly object and then the higher and I’m not sure with even the slowest speed on YouTube how he’s doing that.
Here’s the video as I can’t find anything that uses this kind of method of sculpting without doing retopo:
https://youtu.be/abLo3Gqxbak?si=bkH3YZ5sGjfmB7ga

The simple explanation is: he is not sculpting using the subdivisions. He is sculpting with the Subdivision Surface modifier enabled (sometimes switching to disabled) and of course even though the sculpting tool cannot modify the subdivided mesh, sculpting the base mesh affects the resulting subdivided mesh, too.
As you can see in the following two examples, it does not matter if you sculpt with the Subdivision Surface modifier enabled or disabled, you will always just sculpt the base mesh. The advantage of the enabled modifier is that you can already see the effect the sculpting has on the smoothed mesh while keeping a relatively low poly easy to handle mesh.
Sculpting with modifier enabled and disabling it afterwards:

Sculpting with modifier disabled and enabling it afterwards:


Interesting thanks for the info.  Is there a reason he wouldn’t just start with the multires modifier?  Not sure if maybe I’m missing something and this is a more efficient way to model or something … just seems like an extra step.

@OwenS I could speculate why he does that, but how would I know? You need to ask him. I can imagine he starts with the low poly mesh for easier handling due to a low poly count, but this is too low for him as base for the multires. That's why he applies the subdivision before going further. If this is better than directly starting with a higher poly mesh is all opinion and personal preference and therefore debatable. Once you learned doing this stuff you will find which method is best for you personal workflow. There is no absolute answer since nothing of this is objectively wrong or right.

You want the multiresolution modifier, not the subdivision one.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/multiresolution.html
You can read more about the differences of the two in this post:
What is the difference between a subdivision surface modifier and multiresolution modifier?

Sorry, but you're wrong. This is clearly the Subdivision Surface modifier you can see on the right: sculpting with subdivision, the Multiresolution has a different icon and different settings.

You are correct, I interpreted Owen's question incorrectly. I assumed he was talking about the adjustments starting at about 3:30 in the video. Your answer and his question were regarding the original sculpting with subdivision.
